# Is there any way to not require email address or disable notification upon setting up a member?

Tags: user-registration

I'm setting up a website which will track the users by their role in relationship to the company. I want to use the built-in WP user functionality, but I don't want to send out notifications to all these people that I'm mucking around with the backend, when I have no intention of giving them edit access at all. I just want their information in there for the company's use.

Specific Problems: Regardless of whether I use a plugin to extend WP's functionality or not,

1. Setting up a user requires an email address
2. The email address is required to be unique (I can't make my own test email address primary)
3. Setting up a user WILL generate an email notification

I need to be able to either not require an email address, set up the users with the same corporate email address, or disable email notifications.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the simplest way is to [make a quick plugin](http://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin) that has your own form for inserting users.

[`wp_insert_user()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_user) doesn't require an email address or password, and doesn't generate an email notification.

```
function wpa70409_add_user(){
    $userdata = array(
        'user_login' => 'testuser',
        'display_name' => 'Test User'
    );
    wp_insert_user( $userdata );
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This didn't quite work for me because I do not know how to write my own plugin complete with form. Might have had to learn it, but glad I didn't. This would have worked though, so marking answered.

Answer (score 0):

I found the [Eliminate Notify Email plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/eliminate-notify-email/), which disabled user email notification, despite being defunct.